# How do I generate the metadata of an XML file?

Tags: xml, metadata

I want to know  how to generate metadata of an XML file or what are the elements that can result when i try to fetch metadata of an xml file

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  I suggest that you post some XML along with what you consider to be "metadata" to clarify.  Also mention what system, platform, library, or language you're using.

Comment: The term "metadata of an XML file" could mean lots of different things to different people. Please explain by giving an example of the input you want to process and the output you want to produce.